# How do I know when to use rev = "something other than neither" with the riskratio() function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm learning R in a Bachelor course for the Biology bachelor and had to use the riskratio() function (from the epitools package) for the first time. I'm looking at an example script the teacher posted and I don't know how I'm supposed to know when to not use the rev = "neither" argument. I know what rev does, but I'm not sure how to spot when to use it.

The dataset consisted of the gender and whether or not the person survived during the titanic accident and the goal of the assignment was to calculate the relative risk of death for men relative to the women. We had to make a table with the frequencies of dieing and surviving for both men and women and than calculate the relative risk. The rows on the table were defined by gender and the columns by survival. Men-Died was in the top left and Women-Survived in the bottom right.

[image: A picture of the lines of code and the output when using rev = "both" first and then trying rev = "neither" later.]

My question is why we had to use rev = "both" in this case and how do I decide whether to use it or not the next time?

Thanks for reading this and have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help page says that the expected arrangement of data elements is:

```
If you are providing a 2x2 table the following table is preferred:

                    disease=0   disease=1
    exposed=0 (ref)    n00         n01
    exposed=1          n10         n11
```

So the diseased column is supposed to be the right and the baseline exposure (control) is the first row. If you swap columns you invert the comparison and so you would get the ratio of "risk" for no-disease compared to the risk of disease, not what most people think of as the expected direction for a comparison.

It appears that you needed to swap both columns and rows to get your data in the configuration where the calculations would make sense. I suppose you could have swapped only columns and then you would have been comparing the risk fo disease in women relative to the risk in men.